# anaconda macOS ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'

Tags: macos, python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda, python-3.5

I just installed anaconda with python 3 on my mac (macOS Sierra 10.12.2), and many packages give off errors when importing. It seems this has to do with the typing package, but I can't figure out what's going on.
If I do

```
python -c 'import sklearn'
```

(python being `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)`)

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 51, in <module>
    import types
  File "/Users/geromepistre/types.py", line 1, in <module>
    import typing
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 4, in <module>
    import contextlib
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 5, in <module>
    from functools import wraps
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
```

I tried to dig into the packages mentioned in the error, but it gets more confusing. 
`import types` gives the same error, as well as `import contextlib`. But if I `import contextlib` first (and get an error), then `import types` gets me no error. And I get a brand new error on `import sklearn`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/Users/geromepistre/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 114, in <module>
    types.BuiltinFunctionType, type(Ellipsis),
AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'BuiltinFunctionType'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You appear to be running Python from your home directory, which according to the first traceback contains a file named `types.py`. Since the current directory (`.` in Unix/Linux parlance) is the first entry in `sys.path`, Anaconda searches for modules/files there *before* the standard lib or site-packages.

Try at all costs to avoid naming files for modules in either the standard lib or site-packages, for just this reason. Renaming your file `types.py` to `my_types.py` or something should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, I have no idea how that file got there. Anyway that makes it a not very useful question for the community in the end...

Comment: I did rename the model types.py and still get the same error, is there anything should I do to resolve this issue ?